# ThreeJS 3D objects mixed and linked with HTML DOM elements

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to build a page that mixes ThreeJS 3D elements with HTML DOM elements.  What I'm attempting to do is match DOM elements with coordinates in the 3D scene.

Any ideas?

I'm aware of and have tried out Voodoo.js https://github.com/brentongunning/voodoo.js

But, it looks like the project has largely been abandoned.  I've cloned the repo and tried the demos.  While they work fine on desktop; On my mobile device, if the demo works at all it's super buggy.

Comment: this is an excellent example: http://zachberry.com/blog/tracking-3d-objects-in-2d-with-three-js/

Comment: Agreed. Very direct sample. Be a little careful -- for most (all?) browsers, the DOM element will trail by a frame (if you're using `requestAnimationFrame` as the trigger for THREE updates)

Comment: @gaitat That's awesome!  I'll definitely take a look at what he's doing there.  But, I'm trying to do the opposite.  Determine where in the 3D matrix certain HTML DOM elements occur.  For example, if I have a DOM element with id of "#example".  I'd like to put a 3d element there.  Is there a way to do with three.js?

Comment: One angle I can think of is to replace said DOM element with a canvas and load up a three.js scene there.  But then how does one compute the camera angle/ transform matrix, or whatever based on the user scrolling the page?   Also, would there be a performance hit if you have to load up multiple instances of three.js scenes in different DOM elements?

Comment: Can I assume you are OK with placing a 3d context canvas on top of your 2d context canvas?

Comment: Yeah, that would be fine.  I believe that's what Voodoo.js does.  The problem with Voodoo right now, is that it's a mixed bag with mobile.   That's why I thought having three.js scenes for each DOM element might have more success.