# How to draw/write the text on/inside a 3D sphere object created using Three.Sphere Geometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Here i will make it more clear. Actually i was working on creating three dimensional objects in three.js like sphere and now what i want to do is. I want to write some text on/inside the object at a particular location. I have tried in google but was unable to find out the exact sources. Can anyone please suggest me how can this be done ?

Comment: Do you want to have DOM text that draws on the sphere as an overlay, or text in a texture map that is painted onto the surface of the sphere?

If the former, I suggest looking at this very similar query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768227/threejs-3d-objects-mixed-and-linked-with-html-dom-elements

Comment: first thank you for your response and suggestion. i am sorry i didn't mention it before that  "my sphere object has a texture on it i mean i have applied a spherical image as a texture to my object and now on top of that i want to write/put some text's at a particular location on the sphere.

Comment: perhaps a simple drawing of what you desire would be the best way to describe it

Comment: Draw the picture into a 2d canvas, draw text into the 2d canvas. Use the 2d canvas as a texture

Comment: Hi gman7 actually i tried doing in the way you said, but i was facing some problems in using the image as a texture can you please look at it once and what mistake am i doing here. https://jsfiddle.net/uvojvsLb/1/